# Creating a temporary copy of a table with partitions

Tags: mysql

I've got a little issue and wonder if anyone has come across it themselves or seen a solution.

In one of my reporting scripts, it creates a temporary copy of a table before inserting some rows in order to a bulk update on the source table. To create a copy I used the SQL

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable LIKE source.myTable;
```

Which works fine, apart from one table which is partitioned. MySQL can't create temp tables with partitions.

I can't do the alternative which would be to do...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable SELECT * from source.myTable;
```

If you do that it a) only creates the column definitions to fit the data in the select (i.e. a VARCHAR column will only be defined according to the max length of the column in the select statement) and b) I don't want to copy all 4 million rows simply to truncate them in the next statement!

Is the only other option to create it manually from the information schema? That really feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut, surely there must be a simpler way to do it? Not too mention a lot of work.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you will be doing with the temp table; there may be other tricks to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a non temporary copy of the original table first.

```
CREATE TABLE intermediate_table LIKE my_table;
```

It won't have any records so altering it should be quick:

```
ALTER TABLE intermediate_table REMOVE PARTITIONING;
```

Then create your temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_table LIKE intermediate_table;
```

Then just drop the intermediate:

```
DROP TABLE intermediate_table;
```

Now you can play around with your temporary table without worrying of leaving any permanent table behind if your script halts, which I assume is the reason why we use temporary tables instead of permanent ones.

Comment: That's a really good idea! I can't remember what I was doing where I had this issue (this ticket is a bit old), but that would address the partitioning issue!

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable
    SELECT * from source.myTable
        LIMIT 0;           -- Add this
```

Still creates the temp table, but puts no rows in it.

Comment: This has the benefit of _not using_ a transaction breaking DDL but it lacks the indexes of the source table.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do this in two steps instead?

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable LIKE db1.new_table;`

`Insert into db1.myTable (col1, col2, col3) 
select col11, col22, col33 
from db1.new_table 
where id > 10 and id <20 ;`

Then you don't have to transfer 4 million rows, only the rows you need

Comment: The `CREATE` fails.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the code a bit, tested it on the server and it seems to be working

Comment: Hmmm...  I get `ERROR 1562 (HY000): Cannot create temporary table with partitions`.  My table has `PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(dt))`; how is yours partitioned?